# Oracle Forms App cannot connect to DB (Oracle 10g)

Tags: forms, oracle, authentication

I have a legacy application created in Oracle Forms.

It's a 10g Oracle database, and Forms 6i. Database works OK, I've set up TNS names correctly, tnsping works, I can connect using sqlplus and sql developer.

I think that Forms is also OK, since it gives me a form where the user should input credentials.

The problem is Forms users can't connect. That very first form that is being called has line:

```
LOGON('user','pass@TNS', false);
```

this line gives me form_failure, but I don't know what is the problem. Credentials are definitely correct.

If I try like this:

```
LOGON('user','pass@TNS', true);
```

then forms gives me an additional generic dialog to login if the former was unsuccessful. That won't let me in also (I've tried a lot of user/pass combos).

I also did some debugging (as much as I know in forms developer) but without success.

I would appreciate very much any help or something that could point me in right direction.

Comment: Not familiar with Forms but based on other experience, does `LOGON('user@TNS','pass', false);` work? It isn't clear if you've tired that already. Either way is there an error stack you're suppressing, or is it going into a log file somewhere? Otherwise it's kind of hard to diagnose.

Comment: I am also no expert, but that is the syntax for LOGON. It works on some other similar system. I am not sure if there is something in Forms (some kind of config or whatever) which could interfere with logging in process. Also, that generic form that asks me for user/pass/tns independently (where 3rd parameter is true), doesn't work. Why doesn't that work at least?

Comment: You've still got to supply the DB information somewhere; a TNS alias if it's configured to be able to find `tnsnames.ora`, or a connect string, or something. I'm a bit surprised an app would want/expect users to know that and enter it as they log in - I'm sure it's useful sometimes but I'd have thought rarely. I would expect the app to know which DB to talk to (from an ini file, say). But I have no idea how/where you'd set that. Without an error I can't guess why it doesn't work. Well, I can *guess* it doesn't have TNS_ADMIN set and can't find `tnsnames.ora`...

Comment: App gets its TNS name from registry entry i think. But nevertheless, when debugging, i can see that LOGON gets proper credentials. All three of them. When using those in sqlplus i can connect to DB. That generic login window was only for testing purposes, when I exhaust everything else. But you maybe right about TNS_ADMIN. I'll check that now.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. TNS_ADMIN was not set, and on top of that, there was a parenthesis missing in tnsadmin.ora in my TNS name. The TNS name (with the same name) that i was testing was from tnsadmin.ora of the database, not of the Forms. That confused me. You pointed me in right direction. I was looking for something very hard, when in fact solution was very simple. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. And not embarrassing, sometimes the obvious things are hard to see when you're battling a problem, and it's easier for someone fresh to think of checking and asking the apparently stupid questions *8-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually TNS problem, you have multiple tns files, double check all of them
TNS_ADMIN is not required